# print specific word staring with in text and count

Tags: arrays, perl

I like to find word start with sid=word and sid=text and print and count it the same word.

```
sid=word 2
sid=text 5
```

I have try make some script

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $input = 'input.txt';
my $output = 'output.txt';

open (FILE, "<", $input) or die "Can not open $input $!";
open my $out, '>', $output or die "Can not open $output $!";

while (<FILE>){
    foreach my @arr = /(?: ^|\s )(sid=\S*) {
        $count{$arr}++;
    }
}

foreach my @arr (sort keys %count){
    printf "%-31s %s\n", $str, $count{$arr};
}
```

but show error missing $ on loop variable 
anyone can help me out what i miss.
thanks.

Comment: Does it say where? Which line?

Comment: yes it say line 13 exactly on -> foreach my@arr

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you're looping through a split on default variable `$_`, yes? What happens if you use `foreach my $arr (split /(?: ^|\s )(sid=\S*)/) {` ?

Comment: Also, replace `foreach my @arr (sort keys %count){` with `foreach my $arr (sort keys %count){`. Also, I don't see where `%count` is declared. Make sure it's outside of some brackets, otherwise it will be limited in scope.

Comment: i have try to add split but still not work, for %count maybe some miss on that because I'm really newbies with perl.. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should produce desired output to `output.txt`, with words in order of appearance

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $input = 'input.txt';
my $output = 'output.txt';

open (my $FILE, "<", $input) or die "Can not open $input $!";
open (my $out, ">", $output) or die "Can not open $output $!";

my (%count, @arr);
while (<$FILE>){
    if ( /(?: ^|\s )(sid=\S*)/x ) {
      push @arr, $1 if !$count{$1};
      $count{$1}++;
    }
}

foreach my $str (@arr) {
    print $out sprintf("%-31s %s\n", $str, $count{$str});
}
```